# su: failed to execute 1 sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, authentication, sudo, su

I was configuring a linux server and after an `apt upgrade` this message came up whenever I try to change the user to root.
If I do `sudo su -`, `su -`, `sudo -i` I cannot change user because it says that
`su: failed to execute 1  sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales: No such file or directory`.

I tried to regenerate the locales. Then I added sbin to the path in `/etc/environment`. I also rebooted a couple times. But this error won't go away.

Help please

I am using Debian 6.1.55-1 (2023-09-29)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was a corrupted passwd file. It seems like a failure in chsh corrupted the root shell...